# Does ember.js support segment-literal notation?

Tags: ember.js

Ember.js doesnt seem to support json objects with dots in the objects attribute names (e.g.):

{ "ns1.id" : 14, "ns2.name" : "mike" };

Is this an omission or am i overlooking something? We have services that we are required to consume that support namespaces in this way.

Handlebars seems to support the above using segment-literal notation (e.g. {{[nd.id]}}). Is that also true of Ember? Is the documentation I have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this. It is [compound documents](http://jsonapi.org/format/) which is used to save HTTP requests, it may be convenient to send related documents along with the requested documents.

In this case, a bit of extra metadata for each relationship can link together the documents. Following example shows use of compound documents:

```
{
  "rels": {
    "posts.author": {
      "url": "http://example.com/people/{post.author}",
      "type": "people"
    },
    "posts.comments": {
      "url": "http://example.com/comments/{post.comments}",
      "type": "comments"
    }
  }
  "posts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is Omakase",
    "rels": {
      "author": 9,
      "comments": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
   }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The Parley Letter",
    "rels": {
      "author": 9,
      "comments": [ 4, 5 ]
   }, {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dependency Injection is Not a Virtue",
    "rels": {
      "author": 9,
      "comments": [ 6 ]
    }
  }],
  "people": [{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "@d2h"
  }],
  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "body": "Mmmmmakase"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "I prefer unagi"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "What's Omakase?"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "body": "Parley is a discussion, especially one between enemies"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "body": "The parsley letter"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "body": "Dependency Injection is Not a Vice"
  }]
}
```